# Unable to start receiver (Package name).Class On Camera.open()

Tags: runtime-error, flashlight, receiver

Creating an widget to turn on and off Flash light
Getting Error on turning off flash light
My Widget Class Code

Code In onRecieve

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if(SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget__flash);
            ComponentName componentName=new ComponentName(context,Widget_Flash.class);

            if(Allowed_Flash) {
                if (!Flash_Light_On) {
                    getCamera();
                    Turn_On_Flash_Light();
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.Widget_On_Off_Button, R.drawable.button2);
                    Flash_Light_On = true;
                } else {
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.Widget_On_Off_Button, R.drawable.button1);
                        getCamera();
                        Turn_Off_Flash_Light();

                    }

                    Flash_Light_On = false;
                }

            }
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, views);
        }
    }
```

Get Camera

```
private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Turn On

```
 private void Turn_On_Flash_Light()
    {
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
```

Turn Off

```
private void Turn_Off_Flash_Light()
{
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.release();
}
```

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   io.farooq.flash_light.Widget_Flash: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2287)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                            at
>   io.farooq.flash_light.Widget_Flash.Turn_Off_Flash_Light(Widget_Flash.java:143)
>                                                                            at io.farooq.flash_light.Widget_Flash.onReceive(Widget_Flash.java:74)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

In Samsung J5 Prime (API 23) Code is working fine But in Tried it in (API 16) & (API 19) Flash Is Turning On But getting error while turning off

Comment: Have you tried producing a [Minimal, verifiable, complete example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @barcco23 Check again